# What is the Catholic approach to the analysis of stories, characters, and fiction?

Tags: catholicism, literary-criticism

In the Catholic Church there is a uniquely Catholic approach to almost any human subject. **What is the Catholic approach to the analysis of fiction, stories, and characters?**

What I mean by "analysis" is determining the core values and the internal logic of characters, and how that relates to other characters and the story itself as a macrocosm.  Examples of core values: salvation, love, dehumanization, altruism, togetherness, slavery, etc.  Notice that not all core values are necessarily good.

**Has any Catholic moralist seriously looked and listed core values in stories? Has any Catholic moralist drawn out the implications of core values as they occur in stories?**

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "approach", but Ralph M. McInerny, e.g., wrote a book on [_Some Catholic Writers_](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=8466).

Comment: @Geremia I mean analysis

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Geremia I mean determining the core values and internal logic of characters and how that relates to other characters and the story itself as a macrocosm.

Comment: ... and what do you mean by *that*? There may be things in Catholicism that can connect to the issue (for example, "art is good so let the characters be drawn skillfully" or "let the story itself as a macrocosm be done to glorify God" or "the internal logic of characters must be compatible with free will"), but it's hard to know where you want to go with this.

Comment: @Maverick here are examples of core values: salvation, love, dehumanization, altruism, togetherness, slavery, etc.... Notice that not all core values are necessarily good. Has any Catholic moralist seriously looked and listed core values in stories? Has any Catholic moralist drawn out the implications of core values as they occur in stories?

Comment: I think there might be something to this in Opus Dei; a priest who used to be my pastor explained the Matrix to us as Confirmandii and it totally blew my mind.